# Редактирование изображений на сервере

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток. Заказчик поставил такую задачу. Нужно чтобы клиент заходил на сайт, загружал свое изображение, затем добавлял на него свою информацию (для примера возьмем дату и время). Далее с определенной периодичностью и в зависимости от разных условий на нашем исходном изображении менялась дата и время и отправлялось клиенту.

Вопрос - каким образом можно редактировать изображение на сервере? Гугл ничего путнего не подсказал

ps сам сайт написан на php + laravel

Comment: на фото нарисована дата, или дата менялась у файла?

Comment: нарисована дата. то есть есть исходное изображение на сервере. Надо что бы в зависимости от различных условий менялась дата на картинке. Дату это я как пример привел. Вообще там будет разная информация - текст, изображения добавляться. что то типа динамической инфографики.

Comment: исходник держите отдельно, с наложенной датой - отдельно, иначе потом уже не отредактировать заново, дату налагаете с помощью http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите вот это, там есть абслютно все, что вам нужно и оно легко интегрируется в laravel http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать)

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
$date = date("d.m.YYYY");
$im = @ImageCreateFrompng ($path.'cover/fon.png');
@imagettftext($im, размер, поворот, x, y, цвет, $path.'fonts/10427.ttf',$date);
```

Comment: очень кратко))... ты ему целиком модуль напиши.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться!)